# How to Change a Link's Icon Picture

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, icons

Okay, before I say any more I have to give a warning that I hardly know anything about coding. I'm a huge beginner, and the most I'm able to do is basic CSS and add a link to a post. 
That being said, my question is related to Tumblr, and changing something within a theme I recently installed. I've tweaked a lot of things to my liking, but there's one thing I can't figure out how to change: the picture used for an icon in a link box. I'm trying to make it so that the links listed on the right hand side of the link box are represented by icons, and not the ones that are currently in place. [Here](http://mysterioustrumpet.tumblr.com/) is my blog if you wanna see what I'm talking about. When I was looking through the theme's code I couldn't find an html referring to the icons, and the CSS only allowed me to adjust the positions and colors of them. I'm unsure how to do this, and I've looked everywhere on Google and I haven't found anything so I thought I'd post it here.

PS: I apologize if this is not the best place to post this question or if I'm coming off as unprofessional, that's not my intention and I just want help with my theme.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: Your theme is using [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery) for icons. For eg: Your first link in the sidebar is using -> `<i class="fas fa-user-astronaut"></i>` to show the astronaut icon. **To change the icon replace the current classname with your desired new icon name.** Refer the link mentioned above to find more icons.

Comment: @thebrownkid okay. How can I change the icon to an image I've made myself, and then have that icon redirect to a specific url when clicked on?

Comment: You can replace the code by an `<img>` which will contain your image inside of an `<a>` which will make the image clickable and will help you redirect. Add styles to your image to resize and make it look good with your menu.

Comment: The code looks like this: <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{favicon}">
I'm not sure how to specify specific pictures for each icon that I want to change. They're labeled as "Link One" and "Link Two" and so on.